# C#: Splitting strings after reading TCP Byte Stream

Tags: c#, tcp

I am using C# to read TCP/IP socket data as a string (for eg, LREAL values like '2.2214E-18', entered in a PLC programming code ) which is then inserted into MongoDB. However, instead of specifying the name of the database while inserting the string, I want to give it along with the string. And then, I want to split the string and use these parts in various parts of my program.

Is there any way I can do this?

My objective is to give '2.2214E-18 database_name collection_name' as a string on the PLC side and split it up in the C# code.

For reading the byte stream, this particular block of code is used:

`TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostName, portNum);

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

line = sr.ReadToEnd();`

Looking forward to your replies.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
string[] plcInfo = line.Split();
```

or

```
string[] plcInfo = line.Split(null);
```

or:

```
string[] plcInfo = line.Split(new char[0]);
```

and you will get 2 Strings in one array, the 1st element must be **2.2214E-18**  and the 2nd the **database_name collection_name**

Comment: Can the 2nd string be further divided as 2 strings, like database_name in one and collection_name in the other?

Comment: or just `line.Split();`

Comment: line.Split();... nice one tnxs

Comment: I still didn't get how I can access these split strings for further use in my code. I use:


`var mongoDB = server.GetDatabase("test_database");

  var collection = mongoDB.GetCollection<MongoDBInfo>("sample.RawData");`

How can I use those split strings in the statements mentioned above?

Comment: edit your question and add this code, and add too how the strings may look like... please

Answer (score 0):

Your actual question seems to be:

> In a string whose format I control, how can I store multiple values that I can later split?

The answer is pretty trivial: you need a delimiter. To choose the delimiter is the hard part, it needs to be one that will never be present in the values you wish to store.

In this case, a pipe character (`|`) seems to be a safe bet. So let your string be like this:

```
string input = "2.2214E-18|database_name|collection_name";
```

Then you can split on that character and retrieve your separate values:

```
string[] output = input.Split('|');
```

Then make sure to validate the output before using it:

```
if (output.Length != 3)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("input", "Useful error message here");
}

string value = output[0];
string databaseName = output[1];
string collectionName = ouput[2];
```

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I am looking for. Thanks a ton. I'll check out the  piping function.